# Obtaining Least square adjusted single line by intersecting many 3D planes

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-geometry

I am working with many 3D planes and looking for a Least square solution for below case.

> IF I am having many number of 3D planes knowing only one point and the
>   normal vector (for eg. O1 and N1), and all those planes intersect each
>   other and make nearly very close 3d lines, then how to compute the
>   least square adjusted one single 3d line to represent all those
>   intersections.

To get a clear idea, I have inserted a figure.

- Known: one point and the normal vector of each plane.
- Find: Least Square fitted single line3d

[image]

By kowing the 3d lines like O1-B1 and O1-E1, I know this can be done taking pairwise planes and then by finding 3dline segments. i.e. end points and then by finding the best fitted 3dline. but I heard without doing this and considering many planes at once, can also do this. SO, looking for the solution for that with Least Square. thanks in advance

Comment: How do segments get into it? Everything in the question except that one point where you say "segments, i.e. endpoints" seems to refer to unbounded subspaces; how do endpoints arise?

Comment: @joriki: sorry, it is my mistake of simplifying the question. i will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get that "optimal" line, the key is to establish the objective functions. In order to determine a line in 3D, we need to determine a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$ on this line, and the vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ which is parallel to the line.
Next I will first determine the optimal $p$ and then the optimal $v$.

**Step 1**: determine $p$

It is natural to choose $p$ as the point that is closest to all of the planes.
For plane $i$, denote $n_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $o_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively as its normal vector and a point on the plane. Then the distance between a point $p$ and the plane can be expressed as

$$\left\|\left(\frac{n_i n_i^T}{n_i^Tn_i}\right)(p-o_i)\right\|$$

Hence to determine the point $p$, we can minimize the objective function
$$J_p= \sum_{i=1}^n \left\|\left(\frac{n_i n_i^T}{n_i^Tn_i}\right)(p-o_i)\right\|^2 $$
Denote $P_i=\frac{n_i n_i^T}{n_i^Tn_i}$, then $J_p$ can be written as
$$ J_p=\sum_{i=1}^n (p-o_i)^T P_i (p-o_i) $$
Note $P_i$ is an orthogonal projection matrix satisfying $P_i=P_i^T$ and $P_i^2=P_i$. A short calculation shows that
$$ p^* = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n P_i\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nP_io_i\right)$$
You can check the condition under which $\sum_{i=1}^n P_i$ is invertible.

**Step 2**: determine $v$

Intuitively speaking, the angle between the vector $v$ and a plane should be as small as possible. In other words, $v$ should be perpendicular to the normal vector $n_i$ as much as possible. Or we can say the orthogonal projection of $v$ on $n_i$ should as small as possible. Note we only need to determine the direction of $v$. Hence we can assume $v^Tv=1$.
To determine $v$ we can minimize the objective function
$$ J_v= \sum_{i=1}^n \left\|\left(\frac{n_i n_i^T}{n_i^Tn_i}\right) v \right\|^2 = v^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^n P_i\right) v$$
 Denote $A=\sum_{i=1}^n P_i $. Clearly $A$ is positive definite (you need to check under what condition $A$ is invertible). Let the SVD of $A$ be $A=U\Lambda U^T$. Hence
$$ J_v=v^T A v \ge \lambda_{\mathrm{min}}(A) v^T v = \lambda_{\mathrm{min}}(A)$$
where the equality holds when $v$ is the last column of $U$.

Comment: thank you for the response. I am studying some basics and contact you again for the clarifications.

Comment: again, i am thanking for giving this valuable solution. To be honest, me i am poor in mathematics and lacking basics. if you can could you please emphasis how this describe with matrices, because my objective is to implement this in c++. please.

Comment: The solution given above are all described with matrices. For implementation, I think it would not be complicated. You only need to implement the $p^*$ equation and the last sentence. But for C++, I think you need to have some libraries regarding matrix operation.

Comment: to be honest, the implementation of second part is still confusing me. What should I actually tested? what do you mean by last sentence. please be kind enough to simplify this problem again. thank you